# compass mixin in partial: undefined

Tags: sass, compass-sass, partial, mixins, partials

In my app.scss I import compass like this:

```
@import "compass/css3";
```

and I can use all the mixins in app.scss

But when I import a partial:

```
@import "structure";
```

and I want to use a mixins inside stucture.scss (e.g. `@include border-radius(4px);`)
I get the following error:

```
error structure.scss (Line 544: Undefined mixin 'border-radius'.)
```

EDIT:

app.scss contents:

```
@import "compass/css3";
@import "structure";

// other scss code 

.promo-front img {
    @include border-radius(4px);
}
```

structure.scss contents:

```
// other scss code 

// this generates error structure.scss (Line 544: Undefined mixin 'border-radius'.)
.main-container {
    @include border-radius(4px); 
}
```

What do I do wrong?

thanks in adavance!

Comment: what is the name of "structure" I mean to say its "_structure.scss" OR just "structure.scss"?

Comment: @Chandrakant it doesn't matter:  if the file is "_structure.scss" then `@import "structure"` and `@import "_structure.scss"` both work.

Comment: You need to give a little more code here.  Does app.scss import structure.scss?  Is the import before or after the Compass import?

Comment: app.scss imports structure.scss and compass is imported before structure.scss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, I needed to rename structure.scss to _structure.scss to be properly recognized as a partial.

Comment: wow. Banging my head against the wall for a LONG time on this one. Thanks.